# How to merge tiles obtained using openslide-python

Tags: python, openslide

I am trying to combine tiles in the correct order so they end up as the same whole slide image (.svs file).

The .svs file is read from a filepath according to the function beloew:

```
def open_slide(filepath = None):
    try:
        slide = openslide.open_slide(filepath)
       
    except OpenSlideError as o:
        print("Error" + str(o))
        
        slide = None
    except FileNotFoundError as f:
        print("Error" +  str(f))
        slide = None
    return slide
```

In the picture below I am trying the merge the tiles I got using openslide-python's DeepZoom generator (see code snippet below)

```
def create_tile_generator(slide, tile_size, overlap):
     gen = DeepZoomGenerator(slide, tile_size=tile_size, overlap=overlap, limit_bounds=False)
```

This is how I split the .svs into its tiles:

```
def split_wsi_to_tiles(wsi_path = None):
    print("splitting wsi into tiles")
    tile_indices = process_slide(slide_num = SLIDE_NUM , filepath= wsi_path, tile_size = TILE_SIZE, overlap = OVERLAP)
    i = 0
    tile_indices_savepath  = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"saved","tile_indices")
    save_file(filepath = tile_indices_savepath,filename=name,file= tile_indices)
    for ti in tile_indices:
        suffix =  str(i)
        (slide_num,tile) = process_tile_index(tile_index =ti,filepath = svs_path )
        tile = cv2.cvtColor(tile, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.imwrite(save_path + suffix + ext,tile)
        i = i + 1
    print("done splitting wsi into tiles")
    return tile_indices_savepath
```

The helper functions process_slide and process_tile_index are given below

```
def process_slide(slide_num =1 , filepath= None, tile_size = 256, overlap = 0):
    slide = open_slide(filepath = filepath)
    generator = create_tile_generator(slide, tile_size, overlap)
    zoom_level = get_40x_zoom_level(slide, generator)
    print("zoom level set to " + str(zoom_level))
    cols, rows = generator.level_tiles[zoom_level - 1]
    tile_indices = [(slide_num, tile_size, overlap, zoom_level, col, row)
                  for col in range(cols) for row in range(rows)]
    return tile_indices

def process_tile_index(tile_index=None,filepath= None):
        slide_num, tile_size, overlap, zoom_level, col, row = tile_index
        slide = open_slide(filepath = filepath)
        generator = create_tile_generator(slide, tile_size, overlap)
        tile = np.asarray(generator.get_tile(zoom_level, (col, row)))
        return (slide_num, tile)
```

The get_40x_zoom_level function description:

```
def get_40x_zoom_level(slide, generator):
    global level
    highest_zoom_level = generator.level_count - 1  # 0-based indexing
    try:
        mag = int(slide.properties[openslide.PROPERTY_NAME_OBJECTIVE_POWER])
        
        offset = math.floor((mag / 40) / 2)
        level = highest_zoom_level - offset
    except (ValueError, KeyError) as e:
        level = highest_zoom_level
    print("zoom level set at " +str(level) )
    save_file(filepath= os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"saved"),filename = "level.pickle",file = level)
    return level
```

This is how I try to merge the tiles back to its whole slide image (not necessarily in .svs format but the same image):

```
def merge_tiles_to_wsi(tile_path= None,wsi_path = None):
    print("merging tiles into wsi")
    tile_indices = load_file(filepath = tile_indices_savepath,filename = name)
    slide = open_slide(filepath = wsi_path)

    level = load_file(filepath= os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"saved"),filename = "level.pickle")
    generator = create_tile_generator(slide, TILE_SIZE, OVERLAP)
    slide_dims = generator.level_dimensions[level]
    row_size = slide_dims[0]
    col_size = slide_dims[1]
    channel_size = 3
    slide_shape = (row_size,col_size,channel_size)
    print("shape of slide is " + str(slide_shape))
    wsi = np.zeros(slide_shape)
    for ti in tile_indices:
        slide_num, tile_size, overlap, zoom_level, col, row  = ti
        generator = create_tile_generator(slide, tile_size, overlap)
        tile = np.asarray(generator.get_tile(zoom_level, (col, row)))
        
        row_length = tile.shape[0]
        col_length = tile.shape[1]
        row_end = row + row_length
        col_end = col + col_length
        print("col: " + str(col) + " row: " + str(row) + str(wsi[row:row_end,col:col_end].shape) + " " + str(tile.shape))
        wsi[row:row_end,col:col_end] = tile
        # view_image(img= wsi)
    print("merging tiles into wsi")

    return wsi
```

Here is what the final output looks like
[out.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtLOG.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) can do this merge and join for you. You can call it from [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/), the Python binding.

To load an svs image and split it into tiles you can write:

```py
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("my-slide.svs")
image.dzsave("my-deepzoom")
```

And it'll write `my-deepzoom.dzi` and a directory, `my-deepzoom_files`, containing all the tiles. There are a lot of parameters you can adjust, see the chapter in the docs:

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html

It's very fast and can make pyramids of any size on even modest hardware.

You can recombine tiles to form images with `arrayjoin`. You give it a list of images in row-major order and set `across` to the number of images per row. For example:

```
import pyvips

tiles = [pyvips.Image.new_from_file(f"{x}_{y}.jpeg", access="sequential")
         for y in range(height) for x in range(width)] 
image = pyvips.Image.arrayjoin(tiles, across=width)
image.write_to_file("huge.tif", compression="jpeg", tile=True)
```

It's very fast and can join extremely large arrays of images.

Comment: Thanks for the great info!  I'm marking it as the accepted answer. Thank you for the help

Comment: One little question. Do I need to install both libvips binary and pyvips?

Comment: It depends on your platform and your python version. conda will install both, though I don't know if it includes openslide support. On macos you need to eg. `brew install libvips` before installing pyvips. On linux you'll need a set of build tools as well. On windows you'll need to unzip the library binary somewhere and adjust your path. The install notes have the details.

Comment: I am getting list object has no arrayjoin attribute error

Comment: Ooop, sorry, fixed it. pyvips docs here fwiw https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/intro.html